# Setting HTML tags with GWT

Tags: java, html, gwt, tags

I'm running test automation software that will rely on "id" tags to recognize controls.

I'm developing in java on eclipse using the GWT plugin and have tried using both of the below methods to set the id tag for a button "add".

add.setId("addId");

DOM.setElementAttribute(add.getElement(), "id", "addId");

neither of these are modifying the id property correctly. Have you had this problem before or do you know a workaround?

Thank you for any help!

Jerry

Comment: Adding tags manually in GWT is discouraged. What you are doing is correct in Syntex but possibly not in the right code area. I suggest putting a break point and see if it is executed at all.

Comment: are you declaring your button with uibinder?

Comment: not with uibinder i dont think, ran it under the debugged and the line is being ran, but looks under the variables view I see the id variable for the button remains null after the line is ran. I can't figureout why.

Comment: actually, i got it to run in eclipse such that the element id field is being changed, but upon going through GWT that tag is lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, several browsers (or probably just Internet Explorer) won't let you set a DOM element's ID after it has been appended to the DOM. This limitation would be there even if you are directly doing this hand coded javascript. The browser won't show any error on setting id attribute but won't update the attribute either.

So you need to set the ID before appending the element to the DOM.

---

**EDIT**

From discussion below it appears that you were assuming that setting ID on Button widget's DOM element will set the ID on a `<input type="button">` DOM element. But this assumptions is not proving to be correct because Button widget wraps the `<input type="button">` DOM element in other DOM elements (like table or div).

---

**EDIT**

You may want to try [`Button.wrap(element)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Button.html#wrap%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element%29) method if you want to customize the `input type="button">` element. First create (DOM.createButton()) or locate a DOM element, set it's id, and wrap it using [`Button.wrap(element)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Button.html#wrap%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element%29)

Comment: great! how could I do this? I set the id immediately after initializing the element.

Comment: Button add = new Button("Add test");
 add.getElement().setId("add id");

Comment: So how do you check if id is set correctly or not after this call?

Comment: @Shahzeb, I am not sure about Jerry's use case, but usually people do such things when they have to interface with external javascript code.

Comment: ive been using firebug and a tool associated with the test automation tool, its not being assigned at all at this point, as in there is no id tag for the given element

Comment: Jerry I assume that you know that id is not a tag. Have you tried `document.getElementById("addid")` from firebug?

Comment: hmm, wierd, the button isnt getting its id property modified, but this occurs.

Comment: <table id="add id" class=" x-btn x-component x-btn-text-icon x-unselectable " cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="margin-right: 0px;" unselectable="on">

Comment: does this mean that a table containing the button is being assigned the id property?

Comment: Widget are often composed of several DOM nodes. Button widget is not equal to `button` DOM element.

Comment: is the "x-btn" in the above class section in reference to such a button DOM element? is so, how could i modify the id property tag?

Comment: See my edited answer. You can create an element with DOM.createButton(), set it's id and then wrap it in button as shown in edited answer

Comment: the only problem is i'm using the class " com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.button.Button ", for the Button widget

Comment: so there is no Button.wrap functionality

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I had Selenium test suite for a GWT app and I used ensureDebugId method to set the ID.

Edit - It still seems to be part of the [API](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#ensureDebugId%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element,%20java.lang.String%29)